# Cant pass state to a conditional?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements, use-state

Working on an app where you can post your video game clips. Have two fetches for clip data that are the same thing just ordered in two different ways in the backend (default, and most comments). Trying to render the fetches conditionally. Seems to work when I change line 4 to `switchFetches === true`. But not when I press the button that changes `switchFetches` to false.

App

```
const [switchFetches, setSwitchFetches] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (switchFetches === false) {
      fetch("/most_comments")
        .then((r) => r.json())
        .then((data) => setClipData(data));
    } else {
        fetch("/clips")
        .then((r) => r.json())
        .then((data) => setClipData(data));  
    }
  }, []);
```

ClipList

```
function onChangeForFilter(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setSwitchFetches(false)
  }
```

Comment: Your `useEffect` is missing the `switchFetches` dependency; it will run only once on mount as written. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect

Comment: @DaveNewton ahhh right i understand. sorry for the nooby question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your useEffect will execute once because it has empty dependence array. add `switchFetches` to it for it execute again on  `switchFetches` change.

```
const [switchFetches, setSwitchFetches] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (switchFetches === false) {
      fetch("/most_comments")
        .then((r) => r.json())
        .then((data) => setClipData(data));
    } else {
        fetch("/clips")
        .then((r) => r.json())
        .then((data) => setClipData(data));  
    }
  }, [switchFetches]);
```